# Number losing its format

Tags: php

Whenever I assign number_format to a number, it lose its format as soon as I add or substract any other numbers to it.

How can I set a number variable only once to make sure it always keep it's decimal state?

I don't want to use number_format everytime I add or substract any other numbers to it. I want to set it once.

```
$array = array(
    'a'=>0,
    'b'=>number_format(0,2)
);

$array['b'] += 5.00;

print_r($array);

//Output: Array ( [a] => 0 [b] => 5 )
```

Comment: You don't set a specific format. You do all your calculations, then before you print it out, you format it.

Comment: Do your calculations and use number_format on output?

Comment: It Seems like you are adding 5.00 instead try out 5.01 you will get it

Comment: `number_format()` returns a string. If you then do "math" on that string, you're forcing the string to be treated as a number, which means that a string->int conversion is done. `number_format()` is for DISPLAY purposes, and should never be used for intermediate values. always keep numbers as numbers until you're ready to show them to someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the way `number_format` works. It does not "store" the new format, instead it just returns a formatted string. This string is basically meant for printing purposes.

So when you do

`$x = number_format(0,2);
echo $x;`

It prints `0.00`.

Now if you do:

`$x = $x+ 5.00;
echo $x;`

It will print `5` because **5.00** was added to the **string 0.00** that results in just 5 because by default these variables are numbers. You again need to do a number_format before printing it:

`echo number_format($x,2);`

You can test this easily using the code below:

```
$x = 3.00;
echo $x; //will print 3
echo number_format($x,2); //will print 3.00
```

Note that this behavior is because the decimal points are zeroes, if they are non-zero values they will be shown correctly.

Comment: How can I set the number to always print with decimal? without using number_format everytime?

Comment: There is no inbuilt function in PHP to do that AFAIK. You could theoretically do something like create a new function called `echo_num($val)` and in that function do `return number_format($val,2);`, and use `echo_num` instead of `echo` when you want formatted results - But personally,I do see too much advantage in doing it like that...

Answer (score 0):

number_format() returns a string.  You are setting $array['b'] to be "0.00".

When you try to add 5, PHP now converts your string "0.00" to a number, 0, before it adds 5, to become 5.

If you want to make it into the string "5.00", you have to use number_format() every time.  However, you can use the following code to force it to run through number_format() automatically:

```
<?php
class saveNumberFormat
{
  public $val=0;
  public $format=0;
  public function __construct($val,$format)
  {
    $this->val=$val;
    $this->format=$format;
  }
  public function __toString()
  {
    return number_format($this->val,$this->format);
  }
  public function increment($byHowMuch)
  {
    $this->val+=$byHowMuch;
  }
}
```

Example:

```
$foo=new saveNumberFormat(5,2);
$foo->val++;
echo $foo; // Returns 6.00
```

Note that you cannot var_dump() the object, as that would not call __toString().